# Does "Polkit" make use of linux capabilities?

Tags: linux, authentication, capabilities, polkit

I know that some authentication programs like KDE's `KAuth` can use `polkit` as the backend.And what makes polkit special is that it can grant some specific privileges to a non-privileged process.A functionality that reminds me of `capabilities(7)`.
But does `polkit` make use of capabilities or another infra-structure?
Thanks.

Comment: It is not able to grant some specific privileges to a non-privileged process, it simply do userspace authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[polkit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit.8.html) doesn’t grant privileges to non-privileged processes, it authenticates users and controls access to actions provided by privileged processes. It doesn’t use capabilities for this.

[`pkexec`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/pkexec.1.html) can run a process as another user, but it does so using mechanisms similar to `sudo`: it’s setuid root.